new Date with @let syntax
Using angular 18.1. I write in template:
@let formattedDate = new Date(ISODateString);

and I get an error:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'Date' at column 5 in [new Date(ISODateString)]

How to make an instance of a date in template using @let?

Try (hack) adding class property Date = Date;

yeah, I'd really like to avoid things like that. If I have to mess with a class properties, in that case I'd rather do everything there and just show it in template.

In Angular templates, you can’t directly use JavaScript expressions like
new Date() within the @let syntax. Instead, you should handle the date creation in your component class and then pass the formatted date to the template.
1. In your component class
 export class YourComponent {
  formattedDate: Date;

  constructor() {
    this.formattedDate = new Date('2024-09-15T21:03:45Z'); // Replace with your ISO date string
  }
}

2. In your template:
<p>{{ formattedDate | date: 'short' }}</p>

You can find the detailed documentation for Angular's DataPipe here
